# Guardar datos usando repeater

Tags: c#

Hola buenas noches estoy haciendo una encuesta en Aspx.net usando C#, tengo un Repeater en forma de tabla donde tiene la pregunta y su respuesta tomada desde RadioButtonList... quiero que al dar click en "Guardar" se almacene en la base de datos la pregunta y su respuesta.

[image: Asi quiereo que se guarde en mi base de datos]

Asi quiero que se guarde en mi base de datos

[image: Mi tabla actual]

Mi tabla actual
el hidden es:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="keyPregunta" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("idPregunta") %>' /><tr>
```

y el findcontrol que estoy utilizando es:

```
var keytaken = ((Repeater)item.FindControl("keyPregunta"));
acceso_datos.IdPregunta = keytaken.Text;
```

pero no esta funcionando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes controles dentro del template del `Repeater` puedes iterarlos

[How to Access ASP.NET Controls Inside An Outer And An Inner ASP Repeaters (Controls Inside Two ASP Repeaters)](https://esausilva.com/2014/10/06/how-to-access-asp-net-controls-inside-an-outer-and-an-inner-asp-repeaters-controls-inside-two-asp-repeaters/)

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptPerfSts.Items) {

  var radioButtonList1 = ((RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("RadioButtonList1"));

  //aqui tomas el valor y lo insertas en la tabla

}
```

Ahora el gran problema esta en que el `Repeater` no tiene el concepto del `DataKeyNames` o `DataKeys` del `GridView` com para mantener la key por cada item que genera, para eso debes usar otra tecnica como se menciona aqui

[get the Id with repeater](https://forums.asp.net/t/1596267.aspx?get%20the%20Id%20with%20repeater)

Basicamente en el `template` define un `<asp:Hidden ...>` como ser

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="QuestionID" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

de esta forma podras en el `foreach` usa el `FindControl()` y obtener el `Id` de la pregunta a la cual asignar la respuesta

Comment: Buenos días... tengo un problema con la parte de <asp:HiddenField ID="QuestionID" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

Va dentro de mi repeater???

Comment: exacto, va dentro del template del item

Comment: tengo un problema en la ultima parte no puedo obtener la id de la pregunta para asignarle la respuesta

Comment: tienes que usar el FindControl() para tomar el hidden

Comment: en el hidden tengo esto: <asp:HiddenField ID="keyPregunta" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("idPregunta") %>' /><tr>

y en el codigo tengo este findcontrol pero no funciona:             //acceso_datos.IdPregunta = ((Label)Repeater1.Items[ItemIndex].FindControl("lblPreguntaID")).Text;
....

Comment: me podria ayudar con el findcontrol

Comment: no estas dentro de un `foreach`? si es asi porque usas el Repeater1.Items[ItemIndex], podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo que estas implementando, asi adapto la respuesta

Comment: si el id del hidden es keyPregunta, porque haces un findcontrol con lblPreguntaID, como que estas buscando un control diferente

Comment: cual seria el codigo de findcontrol correcto para tomar el id de la pregunta???

Comment: porque lo casteas a `Repeater` si es un `Hidden` ? el findcontrol aplica igual que el label que tenias solo que es un hidden

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, le comento que ya esta solucionado, utilice un label como hidden.... muchas gracias por todo.